# Why is `function` not a keyword in Python?

Tags: python, class, built-in

Classes like `str` or `type`

```
>>> type("pear")
<class 'str'>
>>> type(str)
<class 'type'>
```

are accessible in Python:

```
>>> str
<class 'str'>
>>> type
<class 'type'>
```

However, classes `function` and `builtin_function_or_method` are not.

```
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> type(foo)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(print)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

They appear as builtin classes but trying to access them throws name errors:

```
>>> function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
>>> builtin_function_or_method
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'builtin_function_or_method' is not defined
```

What's special about `function` and `builtin_function_or_method` ?

Comment: `function` isn't a keyword for the same reason that `str`, `list`, and `type` aren't. (You probably meant to ask why that identifier isn't defined, but the distinction between keywords and globally-defined identifiers is a big one.)

Answer (score 14):

What you are seeing is the [representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of the function type:

```
>>> from types import FunctionType
>>> repr(FunctionType)
"<class 'function'>"
```

This is the "type" of a function defined with def or otherwise:

```
>>> def f():
...     pass
... 
>>> type(f) is FunctionType
True
>>> type(lambda: None) is FunctionType
True
```

The string you've seen in the representation is coming from `__name__` attribute on each object:

```
>>> type(print).__name__
'builtin_function_or_method'
>>> FunctionType.__name__
'function'
```

"function" is not syntax itself, because it's easier to type "def".

A rhetorical question: if `def` was the name used to resolve to the function type, then [what syntax would you use](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) to actually *define* a function?

Comment: > "function" is not syntax itself, because it's easier to type "def".
Why is `type` syntax then when it's easy to create a type object using the `class` keyword? Let me guess. It's because `type` is also used to check the type of an object.

Comment: That one probably predates the unification of types and classes in Python (classes were added to the language later)

Comment: Lol. I was going to see how the class `FunctionType` is constructed in python and I come up with this: `def _f(): pass; FunctionType = type(_f)`

Comment: It's ironic. I guess that a function's properties as an object are not defined in the stdlib but as part of the C code in CPython's implementation. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  You will find similar tautological definitions for things like `ModuleType`, `NoneType` ...

Answer (score 4):

Classes and functions have an inherent name:

```
>>> def foo():
...     pass
...
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x10f951400>
>>> foo.__name__
'foo'
```

The name attached to the object is independent of the name you use to access the object, though when defining functions (and classes), they are the same.

```
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar
<function foo at 0x10f951400>
```

You can even get rid of the variable you use to access the function, as long as you have a reference somewhere else:

```
>>> funcs = [foo]
>>> funcs[0]
<function foo at 0x10f951400>
>>> del foo
>>> foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>> funcs[0]
<function foo at 0x10f951400>
>>> funcs[0].__name__
'foo'
```

The built-in function type is like this: there is no variable that refers to it, but it still exists, and has a `__name__`:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
...
>>> type(foo)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(foo).__name__
'function'
```

Answer (score 3):

A [`Type Object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-type-objects) is returned from the [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function (or `object.__class__`).

You can get a full list of these type objects [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#standard-interpreter-types).

But you can also create your own:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.new_class('my_made_up_type')
<class 'types.my_made_up_type'>
```

So it is a type object that certain objects (like built-in functions) return (namely: [`types.BuiltinFunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.BuiltinFunctionType)) , but **these type objects are not built-in classes, so it is no wonder they are not defined in the interpreter**.